# Time Picker and Autocomplete for App Maker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-app-maker

Looking for a solution to pick times without using 2 drop down menus and an Autocomplete search box.

The autocomplete box example: [W3 Schools Autocomplete](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp)

The Time Picker Example: [Clock Picker for jQuery](https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/)

I am looking for a way i can use both of these and also get the values back out. I am having some issues with not being able to select the element past the HTML widget and non of the JS seems to work.

I dont have anything i can show here other than the copy paste code and a few errors.

Error 1: HTML widget -> autocomplete input onclick cannot find function

Error 2: ClockPicker will not work at all. No errors reported. probably as the element cannot be found or the click function not firing.

Comment: Going to need to see some code, errors

Comment: The code is in both those links. pure copy paste. The only error is "cannot find function", regardless of what function i set it to. im using a blank site for testing this on so there is no other code. its just a html widget.

Comment: If it's pure copy paste then setting up a simple js snippet recreating the error should be simple.

Comment: This is made in google app maker. As standard the HTML widget does not support running JS, allowing unsafe HTML is suppose to bypass this restriction but even then it fails to work. I have it working in Google App Script for Sheets but it still fails in app maker and im not sure why. My question is either looking for an alternative that works, or looking for why it fails to work.

Comment: No one is going to answer your question because no one will be able to answer your question. No code, no errors, no answer. If you need to run JS in your example use [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I fail to understand how JS Fiddle will help in the slightest? It does not support **Google App Maker Widgets** The links i posted to the Copy Paste Code works perfectly fine and i do not need help with the code. My question is Entirely asking how to use it inside the Google App Maker Environment or an alternate solution if that cannot be done. I have told you the 1 singular error that there is as much as the reason why as i know. "App Maker" Is in Both the title and tags, I believe you are mistaking my question as asking for code, I am asking how to apply code in a specific environment.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this? https://i.postimg.cc/1zh3Sx39/femor-22-03-2019-12-12-01.gif

Comment: yes that is exactly what im looking for. is that in App Maker?

Comment: @Morfinismo can you post how you got that working please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new blank application in Google App Maker then please follow the step by step guide below to achieve the same effect as [demonstrated here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFznK.gif).

---

--- **The Auto Complete Input** ---

1). Create a client script and paste the following code:

```
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    var a, b, i, val = this.value;
    /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
    closeAllLists();
    if (!val) { return false;}
    currentFocus = -1;
    /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
    a = document.createElement("DIV");
    a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
    /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
    this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
    /*for each item in the array...*/
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
      if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
        /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
        b = document.createElement("DIV");
        /*make the matching letters bold:*/
        b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
        b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
        /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
        b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
        /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
        b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
          inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
          /*close the list of autocompleted values,
              (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
          closeAllLists();
        });
        a.appendChild(b);
      }
    }
  });
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
        increase the currentFocus variable:*/
      currentFocus++;
      /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
      /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
        decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
      currentFocus--;
      /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
      e.preventDefault();
      if (currentFocus > -1) {
        /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
        if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
      }
    }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}
```

2). Drop a TextBox widget inside the only page you have in the app and add some width to it.

3). Add the following code to the **onAttach** event handler of the TextBox widget you just inserted in the UI:

```
var countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua &amp; Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands","Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Central Arfrican Republic","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Congo","Cook Islands","Costa Rica","Cote D Ivoire","Croatia","Cuba","Curacao","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea","Eritrea","Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Polynesia","French West Indies","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana","Gibraltar","Greece","Greenland","Grenada","Guam","Guatemala","Guernsey","Guinea","Guinea Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Honduras","Hong Kong","Hungary","Iceland","India","Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Isle of Man","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jersey","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kiribati","Kosovo","Kuwait","Kyrgyzstan","Laos","Latvia","Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macau","Macedonia","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Marshall Islands","Mauritania","Mauritius","Mexico","Micronesia","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Montserrat","Morocco","Mozambique","Myanmar","Namibia","Nauro","Nepal","Netherlands","Netherlands Antilles","New Caledonia","New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","North Korea","Norway","Oman","Pakistan","Palau","Palestine","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Poland","Portugal","Puerto Rico","Qatar","Reunion","Romania","Russia","Rwanda","Saint Pierre &amp; Miquelon","Samoa","San Marino","Sao Tome and Principe","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","Solomon Islands","Somalia","South Africa","South Korea","South Sudan","Spain","Sri Lanka","St Kitts &amp; Nevis","St Lucia","St Vincent","Sudan","Suriname","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria","Taiwan","Tajikistan","Tanzania","Thailand","Timor L'Este","Togo","Tonga","Trinidad &amp; Tobago","Tunisia","Turkey","Turkmenistan","Turks &amp; Caicos","Tuvalu","Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","United States of America","Uruguay","Uzbekistan","Vanuatu","Vatican City","Venezuela","Vietnam","Virgin Islands (US)","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"];
autocomplete(widget.getElement().children[1], countries);
```

4). Go to the style editor and paste the following css in the **Page Style** section:

```
.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4; 
}
.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  /*when hovering an item:*/
  background-color: #e9e9e9; 
}
.autocomplete-active {
  /*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important; 
  color: #ffffff; 
}
```

5). Optional: Add a placeholder value: **Type to autocomplete**

---

--- **The Jquery Clock Picker** ---

1). Make sure that you have the required javascript and css external resources added in your app and in the correct order: (First *jquery-min.js*, then *jquery-clockpicker.min.js*)

[image]

> In the above image I'm using the resources hosted on my server. Make
>   sure you host your own or get a CDN cause I might delete them. The
>   external resources MUST be served via HTTPS.

2). Drop another TextBox widget in the UI and add some width.

3). On the **onAttach** event handler of this TextBox widget, add the following:

```
$('.clockpicker').clockpicker({
    donetext: 'Done'
});
```

4). Finally, make sure that you add both of these style classes to this TextBox widget:

[image]

5). Optional: Add a placeholder value: **Pick Time**

Comment: Thanks. The Autocomplete code works perfectly and im pretty sure i can modify it to accept datasources rather than fixed arrays from here. The clockpicker does not want to seem to work though. I grabed the Jquery and sources but im getting an error: $(...).clockpicker is not a function

Comment: @ScottPaterson The reason you are getting that error is because the jquery-clockpicker.min.js has not been properly imported. Are you sure you are using the correct version and that it is being served over https?

Comment: @ScottPaterson Also make sure that the jquery library is properly imported as well. It should go above the jquery-clockpicker.

Comment: App Settings -> External Resources - > https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js then http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/dist/jquery-clockpicker.min.js
and in the CSS section http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/dist/jquery-clockpicker.min.css
these were the links i pulled from the external resources section of the JSFiddle they have available on their page http://jsfiddle.net/weareoutman/YkvK9/

Comment: @ScottPaterson and that is exactly your problem. Those are not being served over https so appmaker won't accept them. That solves the mystery. Once you get that hosted over https it will work.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to upload them to Drive and got https links from there.